# Are Manipulation Events "catchable" for a XAML WebView?

Tags: windows-8, webview, winrt-xaml

I see the Manipulation events for a WebView control, but I notice that do not seem to fire. Is it possible to handle Manipulation events for a WebView control?

I have ManipulationMode="All"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they are not. Not as part of the WebView control at least. It has to be done in the JavaScript of the page where InvokeScript may be a solution. But that's tricky too.

Refer to : [How to handle a JS event with InvokeScript in a WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869690/how-to-handle-a-js-event-with-invokescript-in-a-webview#comment19100558_13869690)