# How to handle a JS event with InvokeScript in a WebView

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-8, webview, winrt-xaml

In order for C# to extract information from a WebView or to react to an event, we use InvokeScript. However, InvokeScript does not seem to property attach to events. What's wrong?

```
private void WebView_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var _WebView = sender as WebView;
    _WebView.AllowedScriptNotifyUris = WebView.AnyScriptNotifyUri;
    _WebView.AllowedScriptNotifyUris.Add(e.Uri);

    // test1 fires immediately
    _WebView.InvokeScript("execScript", new[] { "window.external.notify('test1'); " });

    // test2 never fires
    _WebView.InvokeScript("execScript", new[] { "document.addEventListener = function (e) { window.external.notify('test2'); }" });

    // test3 never fires
    _WebView.InvokeScript("execScript", new[] { "function x(e) { window.external.notify('test3'); } document.addEventListener('onmousedown', x);" });

}

private void WebView_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
    // listen for external.notify event
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like javascript to me. more c#?

Comment: @IanOverton You need to read the actual question.  The code inside the  `_WebView.InvokeScript(` is javascript.

Comment: `document.addEventListener = function (e) { window.external.notify('test2'); }` Are you intentionally overriding `addEventListener`?

Comment: I think that was supposed to be `document.onmousedown = function...` or `window.onmousedown = function...`